# Convolution in abstract braket notation

Tags: hilbert-spaces, convolution

I am trying to express the convolution of two function in abstract braket notation. Here by abstract I mean that a function $|f>$ is abstract and is not yet assigned a basis like $<x|$. So, I can write a convolution as,
$$<x|f*g>=[f*g](x)=<\hat{T}(x) \hat{R}g| f> $$
where $\hat{T}(x)$ is translation by $x$ operator and $\hat{R}$ is reversal operator.  I would like to know if this can be written as $|f*g> = \hat{C_g}|f>$, and if $\hat{C}_g$ is some kind of projection operator. Here is my attempt at this:

Let $|g'> = \hat{R} |g>$, then I can create a continuous family of vectors as, $|g'_x>=\hat{T}(x) |g'>$. Then I may consider the projection operator:
$$\hat{P}_g = \int dx |g'_x><g'_x| $$
and then we have,
$$\hat{P}_g |f>= \int dx |g'_x><g'_x| f>$$
Then I can put this in the $\tilde{x}$ basis (using tilde to make it different from the other $x$), we have then
$$<\tilde{x}|\hat{P}_g |f>= \int dx<\tilde{x}|g'_x><g'_x| f>$$
I don't know where to go from here or if this is correct...

Another approach which I think is the right direction is to consider the operator,
$$ \hat{Q}_g = \int dx |x><g'_x|$$
then,
$$ <\tilde{x}|\hat{Q}_g|f> = \int dx <\tilde{x}|x><g'_x|f>$$
$$<\tilde{x}|\hat{Q}_g|f> = \int dx \ \delta(x-\tilde{x})<g'_x|f> $$
$$<\tilde{x}|\hat{Q}_g|f> = <g'_\tilde{x}|f> = <\hat{T}(\tilde{x}) \hat{R} g|f> $$
So is this then he correct answer?

Comment: A remark - use `\langle` and `\rangle` for nicer looking angle brackets for bra-ket notation, e.g., $\langle x | y \rangle$.

Comment: Ah, okay. I tried braket but it wasn’t working. Will fix this when I get a moment!